# How to get bookmark's page number

Tags: python, pypdf

```py
from typing import List
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
from PyPDF2.generic import Destination


def get_outlines(pdf_filepath: str) -> List[Destination]:
    """Get the bookmarks of a PDF file."""
    with open(pdf_filepath, "rb") as fp:
        pdf_file_reader = PdfFileReader(fp)
        outlines = pdf_file_reader.getOutlines()
    return outlines


print(get_outlines("PDF-export-example.pdf"))
```

`pyPdf.pdf.Destination` has many properties, but I can't find any referring page number of that bookmark. How can I get the page number of the bookmarks?

---

For example `outlines[1].page.idnum` returns a number which is approximately 3 times bigger than referenced page number in PDF document, which I assume references some object smaller then page, as running `.page.idnum` on whole PDF document outline returns array of numbers which is not even linearly correlated with "real" page number destinations in PDF document and it's roughly multiple by ~ 3

---

Update: This question is same as this: [split a pdf based on outline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918420/split-a-pdf-based-on-outline) although I don't understand what author did in his self answer there. Seems too complicated to me to be usable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @theta pointed out "[split a pdf based on outline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918420/split-a-pdf-based-on-outline)" has the code required to extract page numbers. If you feel this is complicated I copied part of the code which maps page ids to page numbers and made it a function. Here is a working example that prints page number of bookmark o[0]:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader


def _setup_page_id_to_num(pdf, pages=None, _result=None, _num_pages=None):
    if _result is None:
        _result = {}
    if pages is None:
        _num_pages = []
        pages = pdf.trailer["/Root"].getObject()["/Pages"].getObject()
    t = pages["/Type"]
    if t == "/Pages":
        for page in pages["/Kids"]:
            _result[page.idnum] = len(_num_pages)
            _setup_page_id_to_num(pdf, page.getObject(), _result, _num_pages)
    elif t == "/Page":
        _num_pages.append(1)
    return _result
# main
f = open('document.pdf','rb')
p = PdfFileReader(f)
# map page ids to page numbers
pg_id_num_map = _setup_page_id_to_num(p)
o = p.getOutlines()
pg_num = pg_id_num_map[o[0].page.idnum] + 1
print(pg_num)
```

probably too late for @theta but might help others :) btw my first post on stackoverflow so excuse me if I did not follow the usual format

**To extend this further:**
If you are looking to get the exact location on the page for a bookmark this will make your job easier:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
import PyPDF2 as pyPdf

def _setup_page_id_to_num(pdf, pages=None, _result=None, _num_pages=None):
    if _result is None:
        _result = {}
    if pages is None:
        _num_pages = []
        pages = pdf.trailer["/Root"].getObject()["/Pages"].getObject()
    t = pages["/Type"]
    if t == "/Pages":
        for page in pages["/Kids"]:
            _result[page.idnum] = len(_num_pages)
            _setup_page_id_to_num(pdf, page.getObject(), _result, _num_pages)
    elif t == "/Page":
        _num_pages.append(1)
    return _result
def outlines_pg_zoom_info(outlines, pg_id_num_map, result=None):
    if result is None:
        result = dict()
    if type(outlines) == list:
        for outline in outlines:
            result = outlines_pg_zoom_info(outline, pg_id_num_map, result)
    elif type(outlines) == pyPdf.pdf.Destination:
        title = outlines['/Title']
        result[title.split()[0]] = dict(title=outlines['/Title'], top=outlines['/Top'], \
        left=outlines['/Left'], page=(pg_id_num_map[outlines.page.idnum]+1))
    return result

# main
pdf_name = 'document.pdf'
f = open(pdf_name,'rb')
pdf = PdfFileReader(f)
# map page ids to page numbers
pg_id_num_map = _setup_page_id_to_num(pdf)
outlines = pdf.getOutlines()
bookmarks_info = outlines_pg_zoom_info(outlines, pg_id_num_map)
print(bookmarks_info)
```

**Note: My bookmarks are section numbers (ex: 1.1 Introduction) and I am mapping the bookmark info to the section number. If your bookmarks are different modify this part of the code:**

```
    elif type(outlines) == pyPdf.pdf.Destination:
        title = outlines['/Title']
        result[title.split()[0]] = dict(title=outlines['/Title'], top=outlines['/Top'], \
        left=outlines['/Left'], page=(pg_id_num_map[outlines.page.idnum]+1))
```

Comment: Never too late :) Thanks for the script which I tested and found that it works as expected.

Comment: No problem, I should thank your for link to the other post ;). I extended the solution to also extract location of bookmark on page.

Comment: 'NumberObject' object has no attribute 'idnum', any reason why I am getting this? I'm using your first example set and I am getting the error on 
"pg_num = pg_id_num_map[o[0].page.idnum] + 1" I am using PyPDF2

Comment: I tried PyPDF2 and it works fine. Do you get this error for all pdf files or just some? Did you look at structure of 'o', what does it look like?

Answer (score 7):

Manage bookmarks recursively using vjayky and Giulio D suggestions.

PyPDF2 >= v1.25

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

def printBookmarksPageNumbers(pdf):
    def reviewAndPrintBookmarks(bookmarks, indent=0):
        for b in bookmarks:
            if type(b) == list:
                reviewAndPrintBookmarks(b, indent + 4)
                continue
            pg_num = pdf.getDestinationPageNumber(b) + 1  # page count starts from 0
            print("%s%s: Page %s" % (" " * indent, b.title, pg_num))

    reviewAndPrintBookmarks(pdf.getOutlines())

with open('document.pdf', "rb") as f:
    pdf = PdfFileReader(f)
    printBookmarksPageNumbers(pdf)
```

PyPDF2 < v1.25

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

def printBookmarksPageNumbers(pdf):
    # Map page ids to page numbers
    pg_id_to_num = {}
    for pg_num in range(0, pdf.getNumPages()):
        pg_id_to_num[pdf.getPage(pg_num).indirectRef.idnum] = pg_num

    def reviewAndPrintBookmarks(bookmarks, indent=0):
        for b in bookmarks:
            if type(b) == list:
                reviewAndPrintBookmarks(b, indent + 4)
                continue
            pg_num = pg_id_to_num[b.page.idnum] + 1  # page count starts from 0
            print("%s%s: Page %s" % (" " * indent, b.title, pg_num))

    reviewAndPrintBookmarks(pdf.getOutlines())

with open('document.pdf', "rb") as f:
    pdf = PdfFileReader(f)
    printBookmarksPageNumbers(pdf)
```

Example output (both methods):

```
Bookmark 1: Page 1
    Bookmark 1.1: Page 2
    Bookmark 1.2: Page 3
Bookmark 2: Page 4
Bookmark 3: Page 5
    Bookmark 3.1: Page 6
```

Answer (score 3):

In 2019, for ones who are interested in a faster way, it's possible to use:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

def printPageNumberFrom(filename):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
       pdf = PdfFileReader(f)
       bookmarks = pdf.getOutlines()
       for b in bookmarks:
           print(pdf.getDestinationPageNumber(b) + 1) #page count starts from 0
```

Comment: This only works if the table of contents has exactly one level (e.g. book chapters) but there can be more than one level (e.g. 1.1 Foobar, 1.2 Foobar, etc.). The table of contents (document outline) is a tree structure, which is why Diblo Dk's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63768713) has a recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but according to the docs for [pypdf.Destination](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/Destination.html) the page number for the bookmark is just Destination.page .

Comment: `.page` or in my example `o[1].page` returns "pyPdf.generic.IndirectObject" which does not provide further return values, except it's property `.idnum` as mentioned above.