# How can I read the bookmarks from a pdf in python?

Tags: pdf, python-2.7, pypdf

I have been searching high and low, pyPdf, pyPdf2, pdfminer and the like, all I want is to read the bookmarks of a pdf, and their correlating pages, so that if the bookmark "chapter 1" is on page 5, and I write print(bookmarks) it will print "chapter 1, 5" or in that direction, any ideas? thanks!

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329748/how-to-get-bookmarks-page-number (first hit on Google...)

Comment: thanks, but as pointed out there, that doesn't give page numbers, just objects, for instance "[{'/Title': '1.\tPreface: Education transformed', '/Left': 88, '/Type': '/XYZ', '/Top': 477.60000, '/Zoom': <pyPdf.generic.NullObject object at 0x021ECF30>, '/Page': IndirectObject(17, 0)}] but  not the page number

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [cpdf](http://community.coherentpdf.com/) command line tool, and then parse the results:

```
cpdf -list-bookmarks file.pdf
```

will produce something like

```
0 "Purpose" 1 
0 "To help students visually organize similarities and differences between three ideas, objects, or sets." 1 
0 "To increase awareness of relationships between ideas, objects, or sets" 2 open
1 "Teacher Instructions" 3
```

where the columns are level in tree, text of bookmark, page number it points to.

Comment: looks promising, how do I use this tool with python? can you show a working script?