# Identifying Bookmarks using Python

Tags: python, pdf, bookmarks

I was looking into PyPDF2 in order to read bookmarks off a pdf.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to read bookmarks off a pdf and then split the pdf base on it. I am pretty sure I can figure how to split once I know how to identify the bookmarks.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It took me quite a while to figure this out, so I put my answer here as it may help others.

The outlines contains a nested list of Destinations ([Definition of Destination Class](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/Destination.html))

And you can get the pdf outline using:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

reader = PdfFileReader(pdf)
reader.outlines
```

For each heading with child headings, the parent heading is in a Destination object followed by a list of child headings as a list of Destination objects.

```
parent_destination
[child_destination1, child_destination2, ......]
```

If it has no child headings then it will be followed by a sibling Destination, rather than a list.

```
destination1
destination2
```

Each Destination contains

- title: the text content of a heading
- page: page number
- other properties

which can be used to split the pdf.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like PyPDF2 has the functionality you need. You might find what you need [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329748/how-to-get-bookmarks-page-number)